# Wcf code works in console and WinForms app (small test apps), but not in our system WinForms application

Tags: c#, wcf

First off, I'm fairly new to WCF so please keep that in mind when responding.

The problem is I created a WCF library (AppCommWcf) that is shared between the client and the server.  When I write a Console application using the AppCommWcf library and call it, it works fine.  When I do the same thing for a test WinForms application it works fine, however, when I use it in our WinForms system application, the client can't connect to the server.  Both client and server are running on my local machine.  I am not using any values in their respective application.exe.config files.  Before you go and use the code below to try and reproduce, as I said previously this works fine in smaller applications, but not our over a million lines of code application so I'm hoping the seasoned WCF professionals can tell me some things to look for as to why the client is failing.  But all I'm doing is using the same exact code located below in between the 3 different applications and it only fails in our system application.

Tests I've run:

- System app server running, System app client running, client fails to connect to server.
- Console running as server, System app server running (WCF code commented out), System App client running, client connects to console server via WCF and completes method call.
- Console running as client, System App server running, client fails to connect to server.

Based on the tests above something seems wrong with the server, but I can't figure out why it only fails in the System app server, but works in the Console and WinForms server test apps using the same client/server code in all of them.

Here's the code from the AppCommWcf library:

```
Project References:
System
System.Runtime.Serialization
System.ServiceModel
```

CameraCtrlCommClient.cs:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace AppCommWcf
{
    public partial class CameraCtrlCommClient : ClientBase<ICameraCtrlComm>, ICameraCtrlComm
    {
        public CameraCtrlCommClient(string bindUrl) : base(new WSHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(bindUrl)) { }

        public LockRequestResponse RequestLock(LockTypeWcf lckType, string camName, int stationId, string userName, bool takeCtrlIfLocked)
        {
            return base.Channel.RequestLock(lckType, camName, stationId, userName, takeCtrlIfLocked);
        }
    }
}
```

CameraCtrlCommServer.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace AppCommWcf
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class CameraCtrlCommServer : ICameraCtrlComm
    {
        public delegate LockRequestResponse LockEventHandler(LockTypeWcf lckType, string camName, int stationId, string userName, bool takeCtrlIfLocked);

        public event LockEventHandler LockRequested;
        static ServiceHost m_svcHost;

        CameraCtrlCommServer() { }

        public string BindingUrl { get; private set; }

        public void Close()
        {
            if (m_svcHost != null)
            {
                m_svcHost.Close();
                m_svcHost = null;
            }
        }

        public LockRequestResponse RequestLock(LockTypeWcf lckType, string camName, int stationId, string userName, bool takeCtrlIfLocked)
        {
            return LockRequested.Invoke(lckType, camName, stationId, userName, takeCtrlIfLocked);
        }

        public static CameraCtrlCommServer StartServiceHost(string bindUrl)
        {
            CameraCtrlCommServer result = null;

            if (m_svcHost == null)
            {
                result = new CameraCtrlCommServer { BindingUrl = bindUrl };
                m_svcHost = new ServiceHost(result, new Uri(bindUrl))
                {
                    OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30),
                    CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)
                };

                m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICameraCtrlComm), new WSHttpBinding(), bindUrl);
                m_svcHost.Faulted += OnSvcHostFaulted;
                m_svcHost.Opened += OnSvcHostOpened;
                m_svcHost.Closing += OnSvcHostClosing;
                m_svcHost.Closed += OnSvcHostClosed;
                m_svcHost.UnknownMessageReceived += OnSvcHostUnknownMsgRecvd;

                m_svcHost.Open();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("The service host has already been started.");
            }

            return result;
        }

        static void OnSvcHostUnknownMsgRecvd(object sender, UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        static void OnSvcHostClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        static void OnSvcHostClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        static void OnSvcHostOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        static void OnSvcHostFaulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Enums.cs:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace AppCommWcf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The type of lock being requested.  These values must match BMS.ElectroOptic.C4IAppOffEnum.BMSSensorLockTypeEnum
    /// </summary>
    [DataContract(Name = "LockTypeWcf", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AppCommWcf")]
    public enum LockTypeWcf : int
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The camera is not locked.
        /// </summary>
        [EnumMember]
        NotLocked = 0,
        /// <summary>
        /// A manual lock was performed by clicking the Lock toolbar button on a video, cannot be overridden except by another
        /// user or an <see cref="Entity"/> lock.
        /// </summary>
        [EnumMember]
        Manual,
        /// <summary>
        /// An action was performed that required an auto-lock and an auto-unlock if not other action is taken within
        /// the time specified in C4IAppSimple.BMSSEOMngrParamsOfRoot.AutoUnlockTimeout.  Can be overridden by another user
        /// or <see cref="Manual"/> or <see cref="Entity"/>.
        /// </summary>
        [EnumMember]
        Auto,
        /// <summary>
        /// A lock was performed by an entity action, i.e. House Call, Line Scan or Investigation.  Can be overridden by
        /// another user or <see cref="Manual"/> or <see cref="Auto"/>.
        /// </summary>
        [EnumMember]
        Entity
    }

    #region LockPromptResponse enum
    /// <summary>
    /// The possible responses from <see cref="BMSEOMngr.RequestCameraLock(BMSSensorLockTypeEnum, BMSEOChannelEnt, int, string)"/>
    /// or <see cref="BMSEOMngr.RequestCameraLock(BMSSensorLockTypeEnum, InfSensorId, int, string)"/>.
    /// </summary>
    [DataContract(Name = "LockRequestResponse", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AppCommWcf")]
    public enum LockRequestResponse
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The video is not locked.
        /// </summary>
        [EnumMember]
        NotLocked = 0,
        /// <summary>
        /// The video is locked by the current user.
        /// </summary>
        [EnumMember]
        LockedByCurrentUser,
        /// <summary>
        /// The video is locked by a different user.
        /// </summary>
        [EnumMember]
        LockedByOtherUser
    }
    #endregion

}
```

ICameraCtrlComm.cs:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace AppCommWcf
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICameraCtrlComm
    {
        [OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/ICameraLockComm/RequestLock", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/ICameraLockComm/RequestLockResponse")]
        LockRequestResponse RequestLock(LockTypeWcf lckType, string camName, int stationId, string userName, bool takeCtrlIfLocked);
    }
}
```

Server calling code

```
using AppCommWcf;

CameraCtrlCommServer m_camCtrlServer;
Main()
{
    m_camCtrlServer = CameraCtrlCommServer.StartServiceHost(bindUrl);
    m_camCtrlServer.LockRequested += OnServerLockRequested;
}

LockRequestResponse OnServerLockRequested(LockTypeWcf lckType, string camName, int stationId, string userName, bool takeCtrlIfLocked)
{
    return LockRequestResponse.LockedByCurrentUser;
}
```

Client calling code:

```
using AppCommWcf;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

CameraCtrlCommClient m_camCtrlClient;

void Main()
{
    TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15); //So I don't have to wait a minute to find out it failed to connect.

    m_camCtrlClient = new CameraCtrlCommClient(bindUrl);
    Binding binding = m_camCtrlClient.Endpoint.Binding;

    binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
    binding.SendTimeout = timeout;

}
```

Here's the screenshots of the WCF logs, hopefully it will help, if you want details of a given line let me know and I'll post it in the comments as I don't have enough space here to post the entire log.
Server Log: [image: Server Log]
Client Log: [image: Client Log]
The exception text is:
The HTTP request to 'http://localhost:10821/CameraCtrlComm' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:14.9990000. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Comment: Are there any exceptions logged or errors in the event log? A random guess: are you running the WinForms app from a network drive or mapped network drive?

Comment: Nothing is in the Event Log, cleared it out, re-ran the application, refreshed the view, empty.  No, everything is running from my local computer, no network connections are used for the WCF functionality.  I'm using "h_ttp://localhost:10821/CameraCtrlComm as the binding url, underscore added intentionally in this comment so it would display.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being I was instantiating the ServiceHost on a non-windows message loop thread.  Once I created my own thread and used Application.Run for it to wait in that thread until the application exited, it worked.  I hope this helps someone else out.